# Ads on youtube player

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have two questions.
1- I have an application which have 10,000 downlaods. Now i want add some youtube videos in my app and these videos are using youtube player on android using their API key. Will youtube allow me to put ads on Youtube player?
2-By the use of Youtube API how much i can requests per day? From the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms there in no limit mentioned. Can i send unlimited requests per day per API?

Comment: To answer your first question about ads, I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications#showing-ads-on-your-website) from YouTube API can help you with this. This documentation provides you a guideline for using the YouTube APIs to build applications that make money. It discusses types of monetization opportunities that are typically associated with several different ways that users interact with online video – video creation, organization, discovery and playback. Just check the above link to know how to show ads on your website.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I am not sure, but I think it is against the rules.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

> the sale of advertising, sponsorships, or promotions placed on or
>   within the YouTube audiovisual content or player;

(2) YouTube Data API has limitation by "Quotas".
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

You can see the usage of quotas in Developers Console.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

[image]

Comment: i am able to play youtube video by converting youtube video url       "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGGQ8NYIVAA" but cant play live channel

Comment: That is odd... Please make my answer "accpet", if your first question was solved. Then I recommend you to post new quetion about live channel.

Comment: You are merely forbidden to overlay the YoutubePlayer with any ads or overlays (views etc), there is no mention about playing your own video ads that will generate revenue via youtube. And they enforce the rule by preventing the youtubeplayer from playing videos if it detects overlays.